# I need to filter date and only get 1 from dublicates which is closest to given date

Tags: mysql

I have a tricky SQL query that I'm trying to make but it isn't going well. This query is about 1 table which inner joins itself to remove any duplicates based on the `starttime` and `actualdatetime`. So if there are duplicates it has to see which one of the `starttime` dates are closest to `actualdatetime` and only pick that one.

This is my old query which isn't exactly looking at `actualdatetime` so im trying to rewrite it:

```
SELECT *
FROM results t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT t2.numberprefix, MAX(t2.starttime) as starttime
   FROM results t2
   GROUP BY t2.numberprefix
) as t3 
ON t1.numberprefix=t3.numberprefix AND t1.starttime=t3.starttime
WHERE t1.numberprefix = '123' AND t1.portingid = '123'
```

I'm updating the subquery for the inner join but im kinda lost on this one:

```
SELECT t2.numberprefix, MAX(t2.starttime), 
MIN(t2.starttime = CASE t2.starttime
    WHEN DATEDIFF(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN DATEDIFF(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime)
    WHEN DATEDIFF(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime) < 0 THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime))
    END) 
FROM results t2 
GROUP BY t2.numberprefix
```

A simplified version of my `results` table(I don't know how to make tables in StackOverflow):

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>portingid</th><th>numberprefix</th><th>starttime</th><th>actualdatetime</th></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>111</td><td>2020-01-08 11:11:11</td><td>2020-01-02 11:11:11</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>111</td><td>2020-01-01 11:11:11</td><td>2020-01-02 11:11:11</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>555</td><td>2020-05-20 11:11:11</td><td>2020-05-04 11:15:11</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>555</td><td>2020-05-05 11:11:11</td><td>2020-05-04 11:15:11</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>555</td><td>2020-04-15 11:11:11</td><td>2020-05-04 11:15:11</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Desired query results would be:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>portingid</th><th>numberprefix</th><th>starttime</th><th>actualdatetime</th></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>111</td><td>2020-01-01 11:11:11</td><td>2020-01-02 11:11:11</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>555</td><td>2020-05-05 11:11:11</td><td>2020-05-04 11:15:11</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `timediff()` and `order by`

```
SELECT t2.numberprefix, t2.starttime, 
FROM results t2      
WHERE t2.numberprefix = '+31636071280'
Order by timediff(t2.starttime, t2.actualdatetime) 
LIMIT 1
```